# How to change co-ordinates based Mapbox map to using a ZIP code instead?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I've set up a map with a location marker, based in geo co-ordinates.

Now I'm being asked to base it on UK postcodes instead. How would I have to change the JS part to center on and place the marker into a postcode (ZIP) location? Thank you for any help here.

CSS:

```
<style>
.marker {
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 40 40'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%3E.a%7Bfill:%238200b9;%7D%3C/style%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Ctitle%3Emarker%3C/title%3E%3Cpath class='a' d='M20,0A13.3353,13.3353,0,0,0,8.4524,19.9988L20,40,31.5476,19.9988h0A13.3354,13.3354,0,0,0,20,0Zm0,18.9166a5.6134,5.6134,0,1,1,5.6134-5.6134A5.6134,5.6134,0,0,1,20,18.9166Z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");  
background-size: cover;
  width: 46px; height: 46px; margin-top: -23px;
  }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div id='map' style='width: 100%; height: 500px;'></div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
  mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFya3VzYXR0cnVlIiwiYSI6ImNrNjk2NXB1ZzBhOWozdW45aHhxZ2hzODEifQ.ZWWxJP61cYov_9EN9PrKdQ';
  var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
    center: [-74.5, 40], // starting position
    zoom: 16 // starting zoom
  });
  // Add zoom and rotation controls
  map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
  // Add marker
  // Add marker
   var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.className = 'marker';
  var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
  .setLngLat([-74.5, 40])
  .addTo(map);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to geocode the location.  So you'll need another API for that.  A quick google search shows that [LocationIQ](https://locationiq.com/) looks pretty good, but I'm sure there's tons.  What you'll do is make an API call to your geolocation service with the postal code, and the response should contain a `lat` and `lng` which can then be used in your `.setLngLat` function.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using Mapbox GL JS to display your map, I'd recommend using the [Mapbox Geocoding API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/#geocoding) to get the latitude and longitude of a particular zip code. [This guide](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/geocoding/) from Mapbox gives a great conceptual overview of what geocoding is and how it works. For your use case specifically, the [forward geocoding query type](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/#forward-geocoding) is most relevant.

For example, suppose you wanted to find the geographic coordinates for the UK zip code `"EC1A 1BB"`. You can make the following request to the Mapbox forward geocoding endpoint:

```
https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/EC1A%201BB.json?access_token=YOUR_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN&autocomplete=true
```

, replacing `YOUR_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN` with the same access token you're using to load your GL JS map. If you look at the response body of this request by copying the request URL into your browser, you'll see that it returns `place_name: "EC1A 1BB, London, Greater London, England, United Kingdom"` and coordinates for the center of the zip code region: `-0.1120425, 51.5245653`.

So, you can parse the response body of this request to get the `[longitude, latitude]` of the `geometry.coordinates`, store the coordinates in a `coordinates` variable, and use this variable to position the marker on your map:

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.className = 'marker';
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
  .setLngLat(coordinates)
  .addTo(map);
```